# error de inserción de datos a una tabla con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

miren tengo una serie de errores e intentado arreglarlo por semanas y nada funciona
melasen los siguientes errores Aviso : Índice indefinido: nombre en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ web \ registrar.php en la línea 23

```
Aviso : Índice indefinido: teléfono en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ web \ registrar.php en la línea 24

Aviso : Índice indefinido : mensaje en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ web \ registrar.php en la línea 25
Conectado con éxito
Error : INSERTAR EN datos (telefono, nombre, mensaje) VALORES (,,) Tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; consulte el manual que corresponde a la versión de su servidor MariaDB para conocer la sintaxis correcta para usar cerca de ',)' en la línea 1
```

y miren mi codigo y pues espero me puedan ayudar gracias

```
$DB_HOST = 'Localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_NAME = 'mudanzas';
$DB_PASSWORD = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$name= $_POST["name"];
$telefono= $_POST["telefono"];
$mensaje= $_POST["mensaje"];

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "INSERT INTO datos(telefono, nombre, mensaje) VALUES ($telefono,$name,$mensaje)";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que NO están llegando los valores $_POST['telefono'] ni $_POST['mensaje'] por el método post.
Debes revisar el  desde donde estás enviando los datos y que tengan los siguientes atributos:
En el formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="registrar.php" >
```

Y en los input's:

```
<input type="text" name="telefono">
<input type="text" name="mensaje">
```

Recuerda que con el atributo `name` se arman las claves del array $_POST donde son enviados los valores de los input's con el método POST. El atributo `id` tiene otras funciones.

Comment: también tengo bien la parte del name en mi html

Comment: muchas gracias ya tengo otro problema >:C